# SQLite Database on Android Not Storing Int Properly

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am creating an Android application to keep track of recipes. I am able to successfully store and retrieve the recipes, but my `is_favorite` value is not working correctly. When I send my `boolean` value (based on whether a `CheckBox` is checked or not), it is correctly sent to my `helper.insert` function:

```
    public Recipe insert(String name, boolean isFavorite, String servingSize, String time, String instructions)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("is_favorite", (isFavorite) ? 1 : 0);
        values.put("serving_size", servingSize);
        values.put("time", time);
        values.put("instructions", instructions);

        long id = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, values);
    }
```

When I look at `values`, `is_favorite` is 1 if `isFavorite` is true and 0 if `isFavorite` is false, which is exactly what I want.

But when I do a `helper.getById(int id)` for the recipe I just created, it always returns 0 for the `is_favorite` column, no matter what value I actually put in there. My query for this is pretty standard:

```
SELECT _id, name, is_favorite, serving_size, time, instructions FROM recipes WHERE _id = ?
```

Here is my table creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE recipes (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, is_favorite INTEGER, serving_size TEXT, time TEXT, instructions TEXT);
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If more information is needed, let me know.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Thanks everyone for your responses! I'm still not entirely sure what the problem was, but after Force Stopping, Clearing All Data, and Uninstalling the app then re-installing it, it worked fine...

Comment: P.S. I also have other tables with `INTEGER` data type in the database and those work fine, so I'm completely stumped on why this one doesn't!

Comment: This looks correct to me. I'm not sure why it would be failing without more of an in-depth look. What does "select *" return (instead of calling out the specific name of the columns)

Comment: It still returns 0 for is_favorites :(

Comment: one thing worth noting: SQLite does not technically have data types -- everything is effectively stored as text. i'm guessing the issue is in `helper.getById`. What does that method do? how does it populate your recipe object?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem is the insert function then. Are you sure that `DATABASE_TABLE` is the table you're selecting on? I'd also experiment, and change the name of "`is_favorite`" to something else and see if the behavior persists our you get a different result. I have had weird issues where "hidden" characters mess up strings. Sometimes changing the name of something removes any conflict as well.

This is a good reason to use constants for your keys, as well (instead of hardcoded keys)